# mySql Column not found error occuring from servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, sqlexception

I query a database to obtain all values from it.The query sometimes executes perfectly but at other times the query fails like this:

```
    select * from myTable  where objtype='EQUI' and scnrtype='C'
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'dataType' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1162)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getCharacterStream(ResultSetImpl.java:2056)
    at com.hastha.marerp.googlemaps.DBUtils.getScreenFields(DBUtils.java:672)
    at com.hastha.marerp.googlemaps.DBUtils.getScreenFieldsJSON(DBUtils.java:754)
    at com.hastha.marerp.googlemaps.DynamicMenuItemBuilder.doGet(DynamicMenuItemBuilder.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEondpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The column `dataType` has `char(8)` as it's data type.

I have tried both `rs.getString()` and `rs.getCharecterStream()` where rs is the ResultSet obtained from this query.I think this has no effect on the problem because the error occurs before this line is even reached.

[This is a description of myTable](http://pastebin.com/NsfiZksB)

This is my code:

```
public ArrayList<ScenarioFieldInfo> getScreenFields(String objType, String scenarioType)
{
    System.out.println("Input args objType: "+objType+" and scenarioType: "+scenarioType);
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<ScenarioFieldInfo> scenarioFieldList = new ArrayList<ScenarioFieldInfo>();
    try {
        String sql = "select * from myTable  where objtype='"+objType+"' and scnrtype='"+scenarioType+"'";
        System.out.println(sql);
        pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            ScenarioFieldInfo fieldInfo = new ScenarioFieldInfo();
            fieldInfo.fieldName = rs.getString("fieldName");
            fieldInfo.fieldLabel = rs.getString("FieldLabel");
            //fieldInfo.sapType=rs.getString("dataType");
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(rs.getCharacterStream("dataType"));
            try {
                String sapType=reader.readLine();
                fieldInfo.sapType=sapType;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fieldInfo.parameter=rs.getString("PARAMETER");
            scenarioFieldList.add(fieldInfo);
        }
        System.out.println("There are "+scenarioFieldList.size()+" screen fields");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        close(rs);
        close(pst);
    }
    return scenarioFieldList;
}
```

Comment: What does an IDE tell you about the object 'rs'? Does not exit this property in there? When you execute the sql query in mysql, does exists the missing column in the result either?

Comment: @reporter Sometimes the query fails,at other times it works perfectly...

Comment: Did you mean that sometimes fails also in MySQL?

Comment: @reporter No failure experienced in mysql,only when using jdbc for a particular servlet...

Comment: And why do you use `rs.getCharacterStream()`for a text column? Properbly the exception raised, when the column value is `null`.

Comment: @reporter Changed my db code to getString it works now

Comment: Only one thing left: Please create an answer and marked as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the code was crashing because I had `getCharecterStream` instead of `getString` which was causing an error in my case.Modiying the code to:

```
 rs.getString("dataType");
```

fixed the issue